# Career at stake for low salary

Tags: salary

I have 9 years wide experience in operation management, profit management.
My work and team work has always got very positive report from my management as it's always problem solving, deadline meeting and result oriented with strong ethics, process and leadership oriented.

However, in my career I never paid much concentration in salary negotiation, in reference to my skill my present salary is very low. At least a 50% hike is expected for the kind skills have been proved. What ever opening is coming all gets very surprise to see my present low salary in result no better salary are being worked out even after interviews are being cleared.

What can I do to get closer to my expected salary.

Comment: Why do your opportunities know about your current salary?

Comment: I agree with Telastyn. When your opportunity asks how much is your current salary, can you say _I rather not tell._?

Comment: Stop ignoring the influence of negotiation on your career. Step one is easy - stop telling everyone you interview with what your current salary is.

Comment: "What can I do to get closer to my expected salary." = You ask to be paid the going rate, or you quit and find a place that does.

Comment: Your current company can't afford the salary you can get elsewhere. It's not necesarily a reflection on you and a good reason to look for a new job. Usually 'more money' is not a good reason, a 50% discrepancy is an exception in my book.

Comment: A lot of people explicitly ASK for your salary information.  There's usually no elegant way to get around it.

Comment: @jdb1a1 Please see [this answer](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/1942/1193) I provided.

Comment: @scaaahu Yeah, that's not necessarily the most elegant approach.  Saying that "I'd rather not tell" is basically the same as opening yourself up to the risk that they will guesstimate that your current salary is perhaps lower than it really is, signaling the interviewer that you might not be qualified.  My strategy has always been to state outright exactly what my current salary has been; I don't think that current salary has as a large effect on salary negotiation for a new job as it is currently imagined.

Comment: @jdb1a1 The key is _perhaps lower than_. They never know unless you tell them the truth. I provided that answer in case you don't want to tell. Of couse, you can tell them if you want to. Do you have any reason to say _I don't think that current salary has as a large effect on salary negotiation_? AFAIK, it always does. Most people would not accept the offer if it's less than what he is making.

Comment: Of course they wouldn't.  That's why it's best to state your salary info when asked so that neither side wastes time.  Your best move is to provide your current salary info, and then if it comes up in negotiation say "my current role has nothing to do with this one." or something to that effect.  Here's the way I see it: you are interviewing and trying to build rapport with the person on the other side of the table.  Saying something to the effect of "I'd rather not say" doesn't build the relationship.

Comment: I do get the "private information" strategy angle; I just don't think that the payoffs to keeping that information private are necessarily written in stone, and that you can achieve the same or better results with a different tact.

Comment: Only once did I tell my current salary. Never again. You get better raises when you say, "I am looking to make $X" in response to that question. If they ask again, then you say I don't need to make as much as I am currently making, I am just looking to make $X. That way you aren't explicitly saying that you are making less or more than what you are asking. By that point, they should get the picture that you aren't telling. And I believe that your current salary has a huge impact on salary negotiation. Why would you turn down 10% more than you are currently making while you really wanted 30%.