# Does empirical research indicate that salary discussions between coworkers cause problems?

Tags: salary, communication, politics

A [previous question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/234/should-i-encourage-my-coworkers-to-share-their-salaries-with-each-other)  asked whether or not discussion of salaries should be encouraged.  I have a different question, which asks for **meaningful research** on the subject of whether or not salary discussions between coworkers actually cause problems.

From [an answer on the linked question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/281/16):

> This can easily happen. I've worked at offices where one person who
>   was a far better negotiator than the rest of us was earning almost
>   double what the other folks who did the same job were earning. It
>   caused a lot of grumbling and animosity because company policies
>   didn't allow for the sort of raises that would be needed to get the
>   lower paid folks up to what the star negotiator was making. In that
>   case, quitting to go work elsewhere was the only way to get a raise
>   that got me even close to what the expert negotiators were making.
>   I've identified my poor negotiating skills to be one of the areas I
>   need to work on.

Personally, I find it a bit of a paradox that salary discussions would cause problems between coworkers, since clearly some people within a company are aware of who is making what, and to my knowledge knowing this information does not cause problems for them.

Is there any **data** that salary discussions between coworkers cause problems, and if so, what does the **data** point to as an explanation?

---

**UPDATE:** In response to the request for clarification for what "problems" mean, there's two parts to understanding its definition in my opinion, who and what:

- **Who:** Might be an individual, a group/peers, manager, company, competitors, and/or investors; I'm sure there's more, but those to me appear to be most likely to be affected. While I'm going to say the same for "what" - I'm most interested in who and what is most affected.
- **What:** As I stated in "who", my concern is who and what is being affected most. Assuming that the topic is limited to for-profit companies, I'd assume that the **who/what for the most meaningful "problem" would be related to pairing of investors and profits**; meaning that salary discussions between coworkers result in less profits for investors in for-profit companies.

Comment: Given the bias we have on our own abilities, every time two people compare salaries, one is very disappointed.

Comment: @blunders,  you still haven't defined what you mean by "problems". If you want "research" citations, you have to be far more specific. Your question is too simplistic (and you should know that if you intend to absorb actual research findings from studies). Perhaps that is why you didn't find anything in the literature and now are somewhat aggressively asking people about this in this forum? BTW, did you ever get an answer to your other question (which has the same problem) about tools to "measure the effectiveness of communication". I think not.

Comment: @Blunders - I think you age going to have a problem finding empirical(number) data about this.  The problems that come from this behavior tend to have indirect consequences.  How do you measure how much productivity is lost to office politics?  And if you can how do you determine what was because sally got the super project and which was because sally said she got a 10k raise for it.

Comment: [Related question](http://answers.onstartups.com/questions/3234/open-salary-policy-good-or-bad)

Comment: @Angelo: SE does not require that answers be found, only that they're ask correctly. I've clearly stated what I mean by "problem" and how I reached that definition. If it still unclear, then please clearly state why and where it might be more clear.

Comment: I believe that if you want to have empirical research on a topic, this is not the right place to be looking.  I would suggest you go to the library of your local university.  That said, I think this type of research is highly unlikely to be very good as it would be something a business would not want to participate in and if you do it outside actual busuinesses where you have actual employees who are being paid unfairly compared to their co-workers then  the results would not be very true to life.

Comment: @HLGEM: Posted an answer with research from eight organizations in Finland via 1706 employee surveys. Not sure why some people believe this is such an impossible question.

Comment: It's not that it is impossible it is just not our job to go searching for research studies for you.

Comment: @HLGEM: First, there's nothing wrong with requesting references, and in fact, that is the very reason the question was not been closed as a duplicate of the question I link to in my question; per the mods. Further, both Chad and I had requested the question be moved to [skeptic](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/) where references are the norm, but we never heard anything back about that request; meaning the mods appear to have decided they wanted the question here. The mods placed the "cite any references" notices on answers, not me; appears gnat's was auto-removed because links were added.

Comment: @HLGEM, well, that's not entirely true.  You're not forced to answer the questions, but if you do, you really are expected to answer the question as asked.  In fact, it's good if we have some tough questions.  That's what makes this site valuable.

Comment: There is no diffidence between non-profits and for profits businesses. They both have employees who want to continue to be able to put food on the table. Many for profit business lose money. Both are sensitive to expenses.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep: Believe there differences between non-profits/for-profits that are related to this question. For example, within some states in the US, non-profits are legally defined as public entities, and as a result subject to FOIA requests; meaning finding out the salary of everyone that's ever worked for a non-profit is as easy as submitting a FOIA request. I intentionally limited the subject to for-profits for a reason, and that is one of them. Thank you for your interest in the question, and if you have anymore feedback, or somehow I've made a misstatement, just let me know. Thanks!

Comment: If you need to discuss salary with co-workers but don't want to say exactly what you make, use this system. Get 2 co-workers. Each take turns doing the following. (1) Add a random number to your salary (that hides it well) and write it on a piece of paper, hand to the next person to do. (2) First person then adds all three numbers together and subtracts the number they originally added to their salary. (3) They pass it to the next person who subtracts the value they added to their salary. (4) Once that is done divide the remaining value by 3. This will give you an average salary between you.

Comment: Somebody making more than you for the same job is one thing, but "double" when there is no objective merit system involved (e.g. commission)? That is a very rare case and will cause problems.

Comment: It is important to distinguish this from a companion problem: Does it cause problems to improperly value workers via compensation? That is, you can blame the employees for talking about who makes what. But you could just as easily blame the organization for incorrectly calculating how valuable a particular employee is. If the problems are mostly caused by the incorrect salary calculation, and people talk about it as a side effect, then you may need to address that problem first. On the other hand, if the organization calculates all pay correctly, then problems *solely* from talking may ensure.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This research paper, "[The use of multilevel models to evaluate
the effects of pay secrecy](http://www.palkitseminen.tkk.fi/pdf_kansio/alahuhta_thesis.pdf)", gathered data from eight organizations in Finland via 1706 employee surveys. It suggests that while the overall effects of pay secrecy on mastery climate is negative at individual and unit levels, pay secrecy can be beneficial in lowering the perceptions of potentially harmful competitive climate for individuals highly motivated by external rewards; note that within this study though that it appears that less than 50% of those surveyed replied to the survey, which might mean something too.

Another research paper from 2009 has a nice round up of research on the topic: [Back to the Future? Performance-Related Pay, Empirical Research, and the Perils of Persistence](http://sites.duke.edu/niou/files/2011/05/Perry-Engbers-and-Jun-Back-to-the-Future.pdf)

In general, in appears that it's agreed that it is a hard subject to study. For example, in this story in the Washington Post, "[Should you know your coworker’s salary?](http://www.washingtonpost.com/blogs/post-leadership/post/should-you-know-your-coworkers-salary/2011/04/01/gIQAxgWX0H_blog.html)", they point out a very interesting finding -- the wage gap in federal jobs between genders is half of the gap found in privately held companies; meaning it's theorized that the difference is based on the fact most federal job salaries are public information.

While not a prefect answer, I'm attempting to prove that there is research on the subject, and likely even better research that the research I've presented. If you're curious how I found the research, here's how: [Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.com/schhp).

Comment: Assuming that the pay gap between genders is a problem.  Most studies on pay do not take into account that men generally are willing to take more risks and will sacrifice other things for pay that women are more reluctant to.

Comment: @Chad: Are you saying that the difference is that federal jobs contain less risks and/or require less sacrifice than private sector jobs, or something else?

Comment: I am saying that the pay gap may not be a problem depending on how you define problem.

Comment: @Chad: Without additional objective research I would have to err on the side of saying it is an issue, since to my knowledge females entering the workforce from college for a few years now have been making more than their male counterparts on average; meaning the overall averages are a poor predictor of the future, and more a sign of the past; just my understanding of the topic, not claiming to be correct. On a side note, just wanted to say thank you for all the effort you've put into this question; in my opinion, you really have been a driving force in improving the question and answers.

Comment: Though the government does make public the salary schedule, and in many case publishes lats everybody know what grade or pay band an employee is in, they still resent the differences. They say I was her longer, I should have gotten the promotion. Also keep in mind that the grade/bands are very wide and they over lap. The highest paid GS-12 make more than the lowest paid GS-13.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep: Any public position that is for the most part not subject to national security oversight is subject to a FOIA request. There are a number of [databases that list per person exact salary information for public workers](http://php.app.com/fed_employees10/search.php), and if you're unable to find their information online, it's always possible to submit a FOIA request unless the request is subject to national security oversight.

Answer (score 21):

Coworker's salary is a sensitive topic. Discussing it may led to one feeling *undermined and frustrated*, as indicated by a case study at *Working Rights*: [My Colleague Was Paid More Than Me](http://www.workingrights.co.uk/colleague-was-paid-more-than-me-case-study.html).

> #### The Realisation of a Difference in Salary
>
> ...“While we were all aware that we were not supposed to discuss our employment contracts with each other, when we went out for a drink after the course we got talking about the merger and whether or not we were going to put ourselves up for it. We had each been sent the job description for the new role and I saw that the salary was five thousand pounds more than my current salary. Over a glass of wine, my colleague mentioned that she wasn’t sure about applying as it was only three thousand pounds more than her current salary, for a lot more responsibility.”
>
> Liz was fuming when she realised the difference in salary, even though she had responsibility for more employees and was based in central London. She spoke to her boss and explained her frustration, but was simply told that her colleague had ‘negotiated a better pay rise at her last review”.
>
> Liz said, “I felt undermined and frustrated that my skills and hard work were not recognised in the same way, so I decided there and then to start looking for another job.”

*Corporette* refers to the case that led to open confrontation between employees: [What To Do When You Make More Than Your Colleague (And He Knows It)](http://corporette.com/2011/12/01/what-to-do-when-you-make-more-than-your-colleague-and-he-knows-it/).

> ...Once he learned that I made more, billed more and was treated as a more “senior” attorney this associate began making disparaging statements to me, where on several occasions the associate has mentioned that it is ridiculous that I am making more than him etc and the firm’s decision makes no sense. This associate also attempts to undermine my opinion and knowledge in every chance he gets. It has become very unpleasant and he reminds me of the super-competitive people in law school who just did not know how to have a normal conversation. Every time I try to work with him on a project, he uses it as a way to tell me that he is smarter and more knowledgeable than me.

Knowing coworkers salary may not always be negative (several years ago it even helped me to make quite a fortunate career decision), but in "salary-transparent" environment / situation my primary concern would be to make sure that team does not drift into counterproductive conflicts like above.

As a programmer, I have specific reasons to be concerned.

Taking into account 10X productivity difference <sup>(McConnell [1](http://blogs.construx.com/blogs/stevemcc/archive/2008/03/27/productivity-variations-among-software-developers-and-teams-the-origin-of-quot-10x-quot.aspx), [2](http://forums.construx.com/blogs/stevemcc/archive/2011/01/09/origins-of-10x-how-valid-is-the-underlying-research.aspx))</sup> - no matter how the salary is distributed, there could be tension involved among developers at different ends of "productivity scale". If one of teammates is 10X more productive than another, they either get 10X salary difference or not - but one way or another, making them smoothly discuss each other salaries will not be an easy thing.

> <sup>- Hey this superstar guy gets 10X more than me - this is so frustrating!
>
>   - Hey I know I am 10X better than that other guy, it's not fair that I am getting only 3X his salary!</sup>

Comment: @Mark Booth: Correct, I'm as puzzled by the update as you.

Comment: @blunders - I'm not puzzled by it, I know exactly what gnat is trying to do. He is trying to improve his answer, which he has done. It may not meet your *research level* requirement, but it is a good *good subjective* answer. I have already decided that I can't meet your exacting requirements, which is why I haven't put any more effort into improving my answer. If anything I'm impressed with gnats persistence, hence the +1.

Comment: @MarkBooth well when preparing update I re-checked [FAQ -> How should I answer?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/faq#how-should-i-answer) and [Back it Up! meta discussion](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/5/does-this-site-need-a-back-it-up-rule). Not that I didn't read them before - just wanted to make sure nothing changed since the previous time I studied these

Comment: @gnat - I agree. I think some people are forgetting is that many of us believe that a flawed answer which recognises its flaws is better than no answer at all. It's interesting that your *no citations* message is now gone, so perhaps published anecdotes *were* sufficient after all. *8')

Comment: what happens when you know exactly how much every developer in your company makes and you are being paid the lowest?

Comment: But is "feeling undermined and frustrated" really a "problem"?  Particularly if those feelings are brought about by a legitimate concern such as realizing that your employer is not offering equal pay for equal work?  With subjects like these, it's important to be wary of falling into traps like "the ends justify the means" and "the only problem is that someone found out".  Also, I'd suggest that disparities in productivity are best addressed in the form of performance bonuses.  The best and worst performers at a given role should have the same base salary.  But the best will get more bonuses.

Comment: related: [Why is discussing pay such a taboo? How can I get people to talk about concrete figures?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/15397/168)

Comment: I agree with this answer in companies where salaries vary wildly: in public sector companies or others with clear, published pay scales, I don't feel it applies. I know (to within £3000) what everyone I work with earns, because I know what salary band their job title falls. When there's no individual variation within the system, the whole thing becomes much more "That's just the way it is"

Answer (score 8):

The "[Fair Wage Effort Hypothesis](http://qje.oxfordjournals.org/content/105/2/255.abstract)" is a well-known idea in the world of economics.  Nobel prize winner George Akerlof and Janet Yellen wrote several papers discussing the effects of open knowledge of salaries across an enterprise.  For the lazy, I will summarize: people that know your salary compare it to their own.  If they feel that they are not being appropriately compensated in comparison to a colleague, they will adjust their efforts in the workplace to match their compensation level.  For the record, I am not so sure that that effort alone is adjusted; I think that people generally prefer to leave, but this hints at another cost for the business.  Sure, you might make a stream of income by not paying somebody what they are worth, but it must be compared against the costs of bringing somebody new on board, the cost of lost time on projects, etc.  On the other hand, people almost always overestimate what their own worth is to the company.

Comment: Exactly describes my first ever job out of college. All was great, I received all the accolades, worked exceptionally hard, brought in lots of innovation and I had a lot of work satisfaction. However, because of an errant email, I found out that I was being paid about 15% less than a much less "respected" (by the team) and capable colleague with similar years of experience. It wasn't intentional, but my attitude soon took a tremendous dip. It wasn't long before I was out looking for a new job and got a really nice raise for making the switch. Good attitude returned thereafter.

Comment: @Dunk - The issue in these cases is usually management problems and having a weak review process